# Get document name in a DispForm

Tags: sharepoint-designer, document-library, display-form

I'm working with a document library and i want to customize the Forms. I need to show the document name in the DisplayForm but the following doesn't work:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
```

I also tryied

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff1{$Pos}" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Name" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff1',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Name')}"/>
```

but i get a correlation with Error `The variable or parameter 'Pos' is either not defined or it is out of scope.`

how do i get the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the document name in your custom display form try this, it worked for me.

```
<tr>
  <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
    <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
      <nobr>Name</nobr>
    </H3>
  </td>

  <td>
  <CustomTemplate>
    <SharePoint:FormField ControlMode="Display" FieldName="LinkFilename" DisableInputFieldLabel="true" runat="server"/>
  </CustomTemplate>
  </td>                 
</tr>
```

Place the above code below your **Title** field appropriately through design view in SPD. I have also added a new field "Author" (i.e. Created By) by simply copying the above code and replacing **FieldName="Author"**.

Here is my output:

[image]

To get document name via XSL variable:

```
<tr>
  <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
    <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
      <nobr>Name</nobr>
    </H3>
  </td>
  <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
    <xsl:value-of select="@FileLeafRef"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It works. Is there also a way to get the value in a variable insteas of using the tag `SharePoint:FormField`?

Comment: Yes you can get the document name through xsl variable. Check my edited code above.

Answer (score 1):

The name column actually has a different internal name. You can use LinkFilename to reference the name column.